# Troubles using the styles

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, vcl-styles

I'm using Delphi Berlin, when I use the styles in an application, I see two problems.

The overwrite prompt in the TSaveDialog component is not showed correctly.

And the chm help window doesn't show correctly the toolbox on the left (Search/Filter..)

Is there a way to avoid the style for the help window?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I am assuming you're talking about a VCL application, since you are mentioning a CHM file. Otherwise, please mention if you are using Firemonkey instead, as that will be an entirely different question.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots of these two problematic screens? Also, which exact styles are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate, [Property “ofOverwritePrompt” for TSaveDialog does not work when VCL Styles are used in Delphi 10.1 Berlin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38485043/576719).

Comment: These are two separate issues. The first one appears to be a dupe. So we've closed the question on that basis. You might need to ask about the second issue in a new question. Dedicated to that single issue. Please provide a screenshot to demonstrate.